# How to use System.net.http.httpclient to create new RT(request tracker ticket)

Tags: c#, httpclient, rt

Need to develop a C# application to create new RT tickets, but the example code for c# on https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST#C.23 is not working.

I have found information from different places but none of them really have example on how to create a new rt ticket by using C# HttpClient.

Here is my attempt:

```
private static async void HTTP_Create()
{
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);

        string ticketUri = string.Format("REST/1.0/ticket/new?user={0}&pass={1}", testUser.UserName, testUser.Password);

        // Doesn't work
        var TicketDataContent = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        TicketDataContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "ticket/new"));
        TicketDataContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Queue", "queue name"));
        TicketDataContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Requestor", "name@email.com"));
        TicketDataContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Owner", "owner@email.com)"));
        TicketDataContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Subject", "Created by C#"));
        TicketDataContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Text", "Ticket body with messages related to this ticket"));

        var ticketContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        ticketContent.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(TicketDataContent), "content");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + ticketUri, ticketContent);

        Console.WriteLine("Response StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());

        var retContent = response.Content;
        var retMsg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(retMsg);
}
```

I got the following response:

**Response StatusCode: OK**

**RT/4.4.2 200 Ok**

**# Required: id, Queue**

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You are getting the results since you have a 200 done.  You need to do the Post portion of the example code.

Comment: But I did a post request here as in the code:

Comment: @jdweng Could you show me in code what do you mean?

Comment: The code in the example after :  2. Post ticket reply with attachment

Comment: Do you mean you have posted an attachment to your reply? If so, I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: No.  Look at the example link you posted.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean now. But I have trouble to create a brand new ticket with ticket content provided.

Comment: There is a section on the page 'Ticket Create' that has sample code that is not c#. (looks like some pseudo code) that you have to convert to c#.

Comment: And using the other tool than your script works? You've said perl is OK, what about something like:
`curl --silent --netrc-file ~/.netrc --url https://rtmachine.somewhere.org/rest/REST/1.0/ticket/12345/show -k`
AFAIK this sends more than one request to the server. 

To solve Cros site request forgery try [this thread](https://forum.bestpractical.com/t/cross-site-forgery/31763), it appears when you get a link from RT and then use it in another process.